# Partial unique index in Postgres to ensure existence of a row that satisfies the constraint?

Tags: postgresql, constraints, unique-constraint, unique-index

I have a users table, a teams table and a users_teams table.

I am looking for a way in postgres to do the following:

I want to ensure that a user always has a default team, a record with is_default true in the users_teams table.

I know I can use partial unique index for making sure a user does not have more than 1 default team, so I am wondering if something of the same effect is possible.

Thank you

Comment: When you create a partial unique index, the unique process affects only the data for which `is_default = true`. If you want effects unique to other data, which differ from the condition `is_default = true`, you can create an additional partial unique index by the `is_default = false` condition.  Or you can create an additionally non-partial unique index.

Answer (score 0):

Add a foreign key that is `NOT NULL` to the `users` table that points to the default team of the user.